# Names and terms

Tags: formatting, indexing

Are there any packages that would help to handle titles and names in the text?

- formatting: italics, quotation marks
- index generation: removing articles, rearranging names to Last, First in the index

Or that is what you have to do yourself? Like these:

```
\newcommand{\ftfilm}[1]{\index{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ftarticle}[1]{``\index{#1}''}
\newcommand{\ftname}[1]{\index{#1}}
```

Comment: Do these formats refer to items in general text within your document, in the bibliography, or only in the index?

Comment: General text. The idea is to use a bundle of commands that will take care of all proper nouns, so you don't have to worry about formatting and indexing or making changes all over the document.

Comment: I guess something like `glossary` might be abused to do this. Or that at least might suggest how to go forward...

Comment: You could even use `biblatex` to do this and either use the `\thebibliography` as index or hack `biblatex` in a way that it generates index entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want

- films in *italic*
- articles in "quotation marks"
- names just rearranged

You state that you want to remove articles from the index, yet `\ftarticle` writes them to the index? Or do you want to remove articles at the beginning of titles, e.g. put "The Fog" as "Fog, The"?

Anyways, you could do it like this

```
\newcommand{\ftfilm}[1]{\textit{#1}\index{\textit{#1}}} % write the movie to text and index
\newcommand{\ftfilmra}[2]% article, title
  {\textit{#1 #2}\index{\textit{#2, #1}} % write "The Fog" in text and "Fog, The" in index
```

The same you can do with names:

```
\newcommand{\ftname}[2]% FName, LName
  {#1 #2\index{#2, #1}}% "John Smith" in Text, "Smith, John" in index
```

Comment: Thanks, @tom! This is very close to what is intended. Is there any possibility to write these commands with one argument instead of two, e.g. `\ftname{John Smith}` added to the index as _Smith, John_, and `\ftfilm{The Fog}` as _For, The_? Probably some kind of regex?

Comment: Probably one could do something like that (not me, however), but what do you d o with names like "Lara Flynn Boyle", this could be two fist names and a last name or the other way around, so I would prefer 2 parameters.